# Почему кнопка не срабатывает?

Tags: python, pyqt

Всем привет!
есть код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

#СОДАНИЕ ОКНА
root = QWidget()
root.resize(450, 250)
root.move(500, 300)
root.setWindowTitle('simple')

#ФУНКЦИЯ С ЛЭЙБЛОМ
def lab():
  newLabel = QLabel(root)
  newLabel.setText('Hellow Wrold')
  newLabel.move(10, 50)

#КНОПКА
button = QPushButton('Button', root)
button.move(10, 10)
#КЛИК НА КНОПКУ, ПОСЛЕ КОТОРОЙ БУДЕТ ВЫЗЫВАТЬСЯ ФУНКЦИЯ С ЛЭЙБЛОМ
button.clicked.connect(lab)


root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

но кнопка `Button` не работает (тоесть, когда я нажимаю на нее, функция `lab` не запускается), а главное если в функции `lab` прописать `print('Hellow World')` и вызвать код через консоль - то по нажатию на кнопку, в консоли выведется "Hello World"..
спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `lab()` последней строчкой добавьте `newLabel.show()`.

Comment: спасибо большое!)

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: я знаю, но тут написано, что можно принять ответ через 6 минут